Increasing search optimization speed may cause you computer to run slowly
When I entered a term into the search bar of my Outlook 2019 desktop app, I was told that not all items are in the results because some items are still being organized (or something to that effect).  I was given the choice to speed up the search.  When I selected Yes, I was warned "Increasing search optimization speed may cause you computer to run slowly".  I chose No because my laptop is slow enough (I'm still on HDD).
I could find no explanation of what the speed trade-off is, even after searching for the above quotation.  Is there any more information about this?
I keep Windows 10 up to date.

Even if your laptop is slow, I would still recommend replacing the HDD with an SSD because it will make your whole system faster.  I have upgraded a number of older laptops with an SSD and the users have been surprised at how much it improved them.

I've been meaning to do so for years.  Just too many other priorities....


Search Indexing Performance: Indexing in Outlook is controlled by the Windows Search service. Performance hits can occur due to various factors, such as the size of the mailbox, the number of items to be indexed, and the presence of outdated filters (like PDF iFilters) that slow down the process.
Indexing Process: Indexing typically happens in the background and should continue even if Outlook is closed. However, certain conditions, like large mailboxes or specific settings, can cause the indexing process to appear stalled.
Optimization and Performance Degradation: All optimization processes, including indexing, consume CPU and disk/memory bandwidth. The duration of performance degradation can vary based on the system’s resources and the volume of data being indexed.
Indexing Status: The status showing a fixed number of items left to index might indicate an issue with the indexing process itself. This could be due to corrupted index files or other underlying problems.

In addition, there is a thread you may refer to: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/outlook-indexing-never-completes-solved/02897a6c-ad09-4637-959b-3cbbef97bf85

Thank you, Joan.  I've marked your answer as helpful since I don't know the cause for the moment.  I have never installed a PDF filter plugin, and I hope that simply having apps like Aacrobat Reader and Foxit PDF editor doesn't automatically install the plugin.  I suspect that part of the problem is that I don't leave the laptop running when I'm not using it, since it cuts down on HDD life (actually, it cuts down on any disk lifetime).  I'll leave it running for today and hopefully, the indexing will progress. It's useful to know that it continues even Outlook is closed.

You're welcome.

I left the laptop on all night and day, but there were 24 (out of an initial 42) items still needing indexing.  A few hours later, however, the indexing was done.  I don't think I'll know the exact cause (or have an opportunity to sleuth it down), but I suspect that a contributing cause is that the laptop is only on for a few hours per day.

When you perform a search in Outlook 2019 and see the message about items still being organized, it means that Outlook is indexing your emails and other items to make them searchable. This process can take some time, especially if you have a large mailbox or if it's the first time Outlook is indexing your data.
The option to speed up the search optimization essentially prioritizes the indexing process, allowing it to complete more quickly. However, this comes at the cost of increased CPU and disk usage, which can slow down other operations on your computer, especially if you're using an HDD (Hard Disk Drive) instead of an SSD (Solid State Drive).
Here’s a bit more detail on the trade-off:

Speeding Up Search Optimization: When you choose to speed up the search optimization, Outlook allocates more system resources to the indexing process. This can make the search results available faster but may cause your computer to run slowly because other applications and processes will have fewer resources available.

Normal Search Optimization: If you choose not to speed up the search optimization, Outlook will index your items at a normal pace, balancing the resource usage so that your computer's performance remains stable. This means the search results might take longer to become fully available, but your overall system performance will not be significantly impacted.


Given that your laptop is already slow, it was a good decision to choose not to speed up the search optimization. This way, you avoid further slowing down your system.

Thanks, but would you be able to cite a source for this information?  I thought that search indexing occurred (or at least was controlled by parameters) outside of Outlook.  It would be interesting to get some insight into the nature of the performance hits and even get an idea of how long that degradation lasts for.  All optimization (indeed all computer operations) take CPU and disk/memory bandwidth.

It seems odd that when I click on the search status, I have (say) 150 items left, but this remains the same from one day to the next.  Does the indexing happen only when the user has something entered into the search bar, and is it abandoned when the user quits the search?  That would be very disappointing, but it's the kind of thing that users should be made aware of.  That is, if it was the case (there must be some reason why there are perpetually 100 or so items left to index).
